# Iterate through table get values in each row. Could be a input or a href or text

Tags: jquery, loops, input, html-table, load

On one HTML Page (`From.htm`) I have:

```
<table class="Contents Stylize General">
    <tr>
        <td class="ProductName">
            <a href="http://mysite/products/product1.html">Product 1</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="ItemQuantity">
            <span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><input type="text" size="2" name="qty[4df7c1555b822]" id="text_qty_4df7c1555b822" class="qtyInput quantityInput" value="1"/></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="ProductName">
            <a href="http://mysite/products/product2.html">Product 2</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="ItemQuantity">
            <span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><input type="text" size="2" name="qty[4df7c1555b823]" id="text_qty_4df7c1555b823" class="qtyInput quantityInput" value="4"/></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the calling page (index.htm) I have this:

```
<script>
    function handle(element) {
        $(element).each(function() {
            var MyHref      = TheHref         //http://mysite/products/product1.html
            var MyHrefInner = TheHrefInner    //Product 1
            var MyQty       = TheQty          //The quantity of <input type="text" size="2" name="qty[4df7c1555b822]" id="text_qty_4df7c1555b822" class="qtyInput quantityInput" value="1"/>
        });
    }

    $(function(){
        var table = $('<table/>');
        table.load('From.htm .Contents.Stylize.General', function(){handle(table);});
    });
</script>
```

I somehow, need to get the values as shown in the handle function for each of Products shown in From.htm.

Keep in mind the only thing I know from `From.htm` is the class names. I have no idea what products are listed or what the input names are. This table is generated by a third party.

Assume that `index.htm` and `From.htm` are on the same website.

Comment: hmm, just to be clear, the first column is always a link? and the 2nd is always a textbox?  and you need the href, link text, and value of the text?

Comment: Yes, it will always be formated in this manner. And I need those values yes please. Thanks.

Comment: just posted an answer for you based on those assumptions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with the given html:

```
function handle(table){
    table.find('tr').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        var href = $(this).find('td:first a:first').attr('href');
        var qty = $(this).find('td:last input:first').val();
        $('#test').append('<li> text:' + text + '   href: ' + href + '  qty: ' + qty+ '</li>');
    } );

}
```

right now i'm just appending it to a ul with the id #test... but you can do whatever you like with those values.

here's a fiddle in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/WdBUs/

Comment: UNREAL!!! That was like in 2 seconds! I reckon I am getting to old for this. Very, very good Patricia.

Comment: PS!! Thanks a stack for sharing that jsfiddle link. OMG!! That tool is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I haven't tested it, but it should do the trick.</strike>

**UPDATE:** Sorry, the $.get processing was wrong. I was expecting to get an object back, but it was just plain html. The best solution would be to create a temporary element, shove the html into that and do the normal search with jQuery. The handle function remains unchanged.

```
$.get('From.htm', function(data) { 
    handle($('<div>').html(data).find('table.Contents tr')); 
});

function handle(element) {
    $(element).each(function() {
        var MyHref      = $(this).find('.ProductName').find('a').attr('href');          //http://mysite/products/product1.html
        var MyHrefInner = $(this).find('.ProductName').find('a').text();    //Product 1
        var MyQty       = $(this).find('.ItemQuantity').find('input').val();  //The quantity of <input type="text" size="2" name="qty[4df7c1555b822]" id="text_qty_4df7c1555b822" class="qtyInput quantityInput" value="1"/>
    });
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot it returns null. If you could have a look would be great. Patricias already does the trick but I am learning and yours is different. Thanks Shagglez

Comment: Perfect! Yours works great too! Can one select more than one correct solution?

Comment: Alas no, would be nice though, wouldn't it? Also marking one as not an answer would be useful.